# PHP's fwrite stops writing to a socket file pointer

Tags: php, sockets, lighttpd, fwrite

I have the following PHP code for writing to a filepointer `$fp` that was opened using `fsockopen`:

```
syslog(LOG_INFO, "Write " . strlen($buf) . " bytes to socket:");

$bytes = 0;
while ($bytes < strlen($buf) && ($w = @fwrite($fp, substr($buf, $bytes))))
{
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "  - " . $w . " bytes written to socket");
    $bytes += $w;
}

if ($bytes != strlen($buf))
{
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "error while writing to socket");
    exit();
}
```

This code works fine as long as the size of `$buf` is small enough. A large amount of data cannot be written completely. I get the following output:

```
Write 4900360 bytes to socket:
  - 11096 bytes written to socket
error while writing to socket
```

btw. the return value of `fwrite` is `0` and not `false`.

Does anybody has an idea what could be the problem? Thanks a lot for your answers

I get the following notices when removing the @ in front of the fwrite:

```
Notice: fwrite(): send of 8192 bytes failed with errno=104 Connection reset by peer in /root/test.php on line 10

Notice: fwrite(): send of 8192 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in /root/test.php on line 10
```

I just sniffed the TCP Stream and I figured out, that I get a

```
HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
```

Is there any fix to this problem? I use a lighttpd/1.4.22 server

Comment: remove the @ before fwrite, it will almost surely print out warning with relevant details.

Comment: fwrite does not produce any warnings. the return value is 0 and not false, which means that the command did not fail but did not write any bytes (according to the documentation)

Comment: I now put error_reporting(E_ALL) in front of my code, and I get the following notices:

Notice: fwrite(): send of 8192 bytes failed with errno=104 Connection reset by peer in /root/test.php on line 10

Notice: fwrite(): send of 8192 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in /root/test.php on line 10

Im happy for any translations :)
...but why is the return value of fwrite not false?

Comment: ..hm ok formatting does not work in comments...

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem right now. Have you found anything on your problem? I am running ubuntu with CakePHP using sockets with fwrite.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
syslog(LOG_INFO, "Write " . strlen($buf) . " bytes to socket:");

$bytes = 0;
do
{
    $w = fwrite($fp, substr($buf, $bytes));
    $bytes += $w;
            syslog(LOG_INFO, "written: ".$w);
    if ($w === 0)
    {
        // end of write
        break;
    }
    if ($w === false)
    {
             syslog(LOG_INFO, "error while writing to socket");
             exit();
    }
} while (true);
```

I believe your while loop was the problem previously, wasn't returning true like it was suppose too etc..

See when it stops writting

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I get the same result here. When I print $bytes after the do...while I get something like 11096 as before

Comment: Can you post more of your code, i.e the $fp = fsockopen part? You can edit out the server name etc... but need to see what you're doing as this should work.
And for the one I posted, what does it say for "written: xx" lines, more then 1 of them?

Comment: Ok read your edits and comments now :D, can you post your fsock command, need to see what you're opening and what kind of headers you're sending. again you can strip out anything sensitive.